# I want to load default text into textarea while page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load the default text into textarea [like this](http://www.healthcaremagic.com/ask-doctor-online)

Usually we can assign the values while page load using below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#text_area_id').val('Hello,How may help you...');
});
```

but i want the text one by one i.e., H then E then L then L then O as we are typing in the keyboard.Kindly refer the link i have given.

(forgive my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this plugin](http://labs.rnzmedia.co.za/typewriter.html) (jquery.typewriter)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with window.setInterval and some string manipulation, see this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/FFDXq/

(Done in a rush, so there may be an out-by-one error in there)